# How many Borel conjectures are there

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, set-theory, differential-topology

The following may be referred to as *Borel conjecture*:

Every strong measure zero set of reals is countable.

On the other hand [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_conjecture) refers to the following as the Borel conjecture:

Let  $M$ and $N$ be closed and aspherical topological manifolds, and let
$f:M\to N$
be a homotopy equivalence. The Borel conjecture states that the map $f$  is homotopic to a homeomorphism.

The two seem to be unrelated. Is the naming confusing coincidence? Or are they related? Moreover are they really still *conjectures* or were they subsequently solved? The article I link to does not mention the status of the "conjecture(s)".

Comment: The first Borel conjecture you mentioned has been solved. The statement is independent of the standard axioms of set theory, including the axiom of choice.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo Thank you! What about the second conjecture? Are they related?

Comment: The second Borel conjecture you mention is one of the major open problems of geometric topology. A weaker form of this conjecture, the Novikov conjecture, remains open, so certainly the Borel conjecture is open as well. I'm pretty sure the two Borel conjectures you mention are unrelated.

Comment: @HenryT.Horton Thank you for your comment it is very helpful.

Comment: Why is it at all surprising that the dude may have had several conjectures or that several dudes happened to share a name?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These Borels are different people.

The first one is [Émile Borel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89mile_Borel), whereas the second one is [Armand Borel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armand_Borel). From the latter's Wikipedia page,

> He used to answer the question of whether he was related to Émile Borel alternately by saying he was a nephew, and no relation.

Comment: Then probably no relation?